# AngularJS pass cookies without allowCredentials

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I've developed an Angular based web shop that works against Woocommerce as a backend. When I add an item to the cart, the server responds with a "Set-Cookie" header where the WooCommerce session id resides. This cookie should be passed to the server upon the next request, so that the server knows that it's the same session. However, if I don't have the `allowCredentials` flag set in my request from the Angular $http call, the cookies isn't passed to the server.

What we did first was to set the `allowCredentials`to `true`, and it worked great! Now we are developing an Ionic app for the same shop. We can't have the allowCredentials flag set, because it isn't allowed together with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, which we need to have set because the API is being called from different origins because of the app.

How can we make Angular pass the cookies without having the allowCredentials flag set?

Comment: Try to put all your white listed origins (comma separated) as a value of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, instead of `*`, because you can't mix `*` with `allowCredentials` option set to `true`.

Comment: How should I do that when I have hundreds of mobiles which will try to connect? I can't list every single one of them, right?

Comment: Simple and stupid solution, is to put the origin of the request, as a value for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, but keep in mind, it's risky

Comment: Yes but I don't have a single origin of request, but many (one per device)

Comment: Another way to avoid this problem, is to make local proxy server to deal with the server

Comment: I meant by origin of the request, something like `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin)`